# Scroll Progress Animation on div border

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, border

I want make a progress scroll bar all arround the border of a div element...
Like the "go up" button that fill all arround the border when a user scroll down... like [this](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/css-border-animation/#h-button-hover-border-animations-css) animation (just to understand)

I try whit this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/blog/scroll-progress-animations-in-css/) but i don't realy understood how can i do...

Ty!